# How to find which port has a static IP

Tags: cisco, switch, ip, ipv4

My colleague set up a static IP on a switch, but didn't tell me where and what port, is there a command to run that will find which port has the static IP set up on.

Comment: You will need to provide at least the switch brand and model. On a switch a management IP is generally set on a VLAN or a management interface, not on a specific port / physical interface (except when there's a dedicated physical management interface but on this case it is obvious).

Comment: Do you have access to the switch ? In most cases on a switch you would add an IP to a VLAN interface, not to a physical port. On a Cisco, you could start with "show ip int brief", assuming, again, that you have access to the switch. Other brands have a similar command.

Comment: It is a cisco 9300, i'll try that now thanks

Comment: @JeremyGibbons you should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases on a switch you would add an IP to a VLAN interface, not to a physical port.

Regardless, on a Cisco, you could start with the "show ip int brief" command, assuming, again, that you have access to the switch. Other brands have a similar command.

This will show you something like this:

```
Router# show ip interface brief
Interface     IP-Address     OK?  Method  Status                  Protocol
Ethernet0     10.108.00.5    YES  NVRAM   up                      up      
Ethernet1     unassigned     YES  unset   administratively down   down    
Loopback0     10.108.200.5   YES  NVRAM   up                      up      
Serial0       10.108.100.5   YES  NVRAM   up                      up      
Serial1       10.108.40.5    YES  NVRAM   up                      up      
Serial2       10.108.100.5   YES  manual  up                      up      
Serial3       unassigned     YES  unset   administratively down   down
```